# query to retrieve millions of records and display them in pages

Tags: sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, pagination, spring-jdbc

We have a problem:

I'm using J2EE technologies. Spring, Hibernate.
We have millions of records in the a table with 2 columns. Clm1-Primary Key. Column 2 is description column.
I have a web page with textbox which allows users to enter any word and hit search.
If I run the query I might have millions of records.
I should display the results in pages (with 10 records per page) without crashing the server.

How can I do this? Can I just use resulSet, setmax etc...?

Answer (score 0):

You can Create Criteria like this

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Restrictions.like("descriptions", "search key")
    .setMaxResults(10)
    .list();
```

If you want to search in descriptions then please set index in descriptions filed so you can search more faster when more records are in database.

here is Doc for more details.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: If I use setMaxResults, how do the next 10 results populate onto the next page?

Comment: criteria.setFirstResult(iDisplayStart);criteria.setMaxResults(iDisplayLength); use this